# MongoDB date field does not save current time

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB to store all the data. Among the fields I have set, there is one that is a Date type field, which is formatted using Moment.js this way:

`moment().format()`

This is working properly, but when I push the data to the model before saving to MongoDB, for some reason the Date is two hours earlier instead of the current time. I have been looking for help with no luck. Is there any way to set MongoDB Timezone?

This is the field in the model:

```
published_at: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
}
```

And the controller with the example of the real dates:

```
function createComment(req, res) {
    
    const comment = new Comment();

    const { user, content, post_slug, post_title, post_type , post_id, thumb } = req.body;

    comment.user = user;
    comment.content = content;
    comment.post_slug = post_slug;
    comment.post_id = post_id;
    comment.post_title = post_title;
    comment.post_type = post_type;
    comment.published_at = moment().format();
    comment.thumb = thumb;
    comment.deleted = false;

    console.log(moment().format()); //2021-08-16T16:10:15+02:00
    console.log(comment.published_at); //2021-08-16T14:10:15.000Z

    if (!user || !content || !post_id || !post_slug || !post_type || !post_title) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you are asking for type date. Try passing a type date value because moment().format() returns a string.

```
const today = moment().toDate();
console.log(typeof(today)) //Date

const todayString = moment().format();
console.log(typeof(todayString)) //string
```

If that doesn't solve the issue another option is to parse the data to the timezone that you want at the time of consulting data from that table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately isn't working, it keeps saving 2 hours earlier instead of current time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
comment.published_at = moment().toDate();
```

MongoDB stores date/time always and only as UTC time. If you need to preserve the client input time zone, then you need to store this in a separate field, e.g.:

```
comment.published_at = moment().toDate();
comment.time_zone = moment.tz.guess();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this is not working for me. It keeps saving two hours earlier instead of current time. `moment().format()` its ok regarding current time, the problem is when I save it to the object `comment.published_at = moment().format()`. Tried with your solution too.